# Adding Additional Text To a Product Category Page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Woocommerce has product category pages. They act just like wordpress regular category pages, but for products rather than posts.

In the product category editor there is a description box where you can add text. The text becomes displayed below the category page title when viewing that product category page.

I am trying to find a way to also add content below the products as well. Basically I want to have a 1,000 word article underneath my products on that product category page for SEO purpose.

However, I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

To display the text on the category page below the products, you need to add this code to the beginning of the file wp-includes/functions.php, before code "mysql2date ($ format, $ date, $ translate = true) {"

```
    add_action( 'init', 'wpm_product_cat_register_meta' );
/**
 * Register details product_cat meta.
 *
 * Register the details metabox for WooCommerce product categories.
 *
 */
function wpm_product_cat_register_meta() {
    register_meta( 'term', 'details', 'wpm_sanitize_details' );
}
/**
 * Sanitize the details custom meta field.
 *
 * @param  string $details The existing details field.
 * @return string          The sanitized details field
 */
function wpm_sanitize_details( $details ) {
    return wp_kses_post( $details );
}


add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'wpm_product_cat_add_details_meta' );
/**
 * Add a details metabox to the Add New Product Category page.
 *
 * For adding a details metabox to the WordPress admin when
 * creating new product categories in WooCommerce.
 *
 */
function wpm_product_cat_add_details_meta() {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'wpm_product_cat_details_nonce' );
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="wpm-product-cat-details"><?php esc_html_e( 'Details', 'wpm' ); ?></label>
        <textarea name="wpm-product-cat-details" id="wpm-product-cat-details" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
        <p class="description"><?php esc_html_e( 'Detailed category info to appear below the product list', 'wpm' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}


add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'wpm_product_cat_edit_details_meta' );
/**
 * Add a details metabox to the Edit Product Category page.
 *
 * For adding a details metabox to the WordPress admin when
 * editing an existing product category in WooCommerce.
 *
 * @param  object $term The existing term object.
 */
function wpm_product_cat_edit_details_meta( $term ) {
    $product_cat_details = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'details', true );
    if ( ! $product_cat_details ) {
        $product_cat_details = '';
    }
    $settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'wpm-product-cat-details' );
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="wpm-product-cat-details"><?php esc_html_e( 'Details', 'wpm' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'wpm_product_cat_details_nonce' ); ?>
            <?php wp_editor( wpm_sanitize_details( $product_cat_details ), 'product_cat_details', $settings ); ?>
            <p class="description"><?php esc_html_e( 'Detailed category info to appear below the product list','wpm' ); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'create_product_cat', 'wpm_product_cat_details_meta_save' );
add_action( 'edit_product_cat', 'wpm_product_cat_details_meta_save' );
/**
 * Save Product Category details meta.
 *
 * Save the product_cat details meta POSTed from the
 * edit product_cat page or the add product_cat page.
 *
 * @param  int $term_id The term ID of the term to update.
 */
function wpm_product_cat_details_meta_save( $term_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['wpm_product_cat_details_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpm_product_cat_details_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $old_details = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'details', true );
    $new_details = isset( $_POST['wpm-product-cat-details'] ) ? $_POST['wpm-product-cat-details'] : '';
    if ( $old_details && '' === $new_details ) {
        delete_term_meta( $term_id, 'details' );
    } else if ( $old_details !== $new_details ) {
        update_term_meta(
            $term_id,
            'details',
            wpm_sanitize_details( $new_details )
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'wpm_product_cat_display_details_meta' );
/**
 * Display details meta on Product Category archives.
 *
 */
function wpm_product_cat_display_details_meta() {
    if ( ! is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $t_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $details = get_term_meta( $t_id, 'details', true );
    if ( '' !== $details ) {
        ?>
        <div class="product-cat-details">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_kses_post( $details ) ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

You will get an additional field in the category properties named "Details". Add your article here and you will get the text underneath the products list on category page. This will work for each category.

Answer (score 0):

There are countless ways to achieve this. One way is to [override the archive-product.php template](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/), and include the content there.

The general steps are:

1. Create a `/woocommerce/` directory in your theme root
2. Copy the **archive-product.php** template from `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/` to your newly created folder.
3. Edit and save the copied file.

Read more about template overrides in [the WooCommerce docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

Comment: Isnt that just the process to safely start editing the code in whatever way it needs to be....coded?  Also that page you sent me has this message "Please note: when creating woocommerce.php in your theme’s folder, you won’t then be able to override the woocommerce/archive-product.php custom template (in your theme) as woocommerce.php has the priority over all other template files. This is intended to prevent display issues."

Comment: I was under the impression you need to add another text box/custome field in category.php or something like that and then call it from archive-product.php.....As you can I am absolutely clueless....theres got to be a simple way to do this.

Comment: I mentioned the simple way to do it. **archive-product.php** and **category.php** have no equivalents in the admin. They're completely automatically generated. You need to follow my steps above, and hard-code the text you want below the products. The only other viable alternative is to write your own plugin to add a new options page to the admin, and then modify the archive template to pull in data programatically from that options page.